How to fetch Power bi access token
How can we obtain the token for a power bi dashboard dynamically without using azure AD.
I have created a dashboard which is embedded into my react application, but for now I have been pasting the my access token manually but copying it from the power bi website using the console command copy(powerBIAccessToken) as explained in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5KFY5Jh1Uc,
but I would like to fetch this token using code instead of pasting manually into the access token field.screenshot of code where we put access token
I want to fetch the token dynamically using code, and would like to do it without using azure AD

Power BI only accepts access tokens from Entra ID (aka AAD).

I am not aware of this functionality, it feels a bit contra productive to its purpose. The idea is to have a secure mechanism to get a token and use this in your application to get access. Now you are saying: I would like to have an API where I can login to with a token and generate more tokens? Maybe I misunderstood..

Refer to this Microsoft Documentation on how to generate a Microsoft Entra Token using API call - Embedded Analytics Token.
Refer the same doc mentioned above and understand which token suits your scenario either Microsoft Entra Token or an Embed Token.
Since you're embedding in React application, you can use msal-react library and generate the token using the msal hooks.
Refer to the React Developer Samples for the sample code. If you still have questions, you need to rephrase the question in detailed.
